# Linksys WRT54G2, what revision is this router?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I would like to put DD-WRT on my router (Linksys WRT54G2) but the website says that the latest revision 4 (I think) isn't supported.  How do I check what revision router I have?

Thanks much

Comment: GV4 should be supported, GV5 wasn't at one point, since it has less ram, and dosen't run linux. GLs on the other hand will *always* run dd-wrt with no issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look underneath the router and check for the "ver. [number]" in the model number. And here are some more [details on the WRT54GS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GS).

[image: WRT54G underside]

Comment: @Sarge, thanks. For new users of this hardware, some of which has several bar-codes and numbers, it just seemed necessary…

Answer (score 0):

You should find the information underneath the router. Look for label "Model no:". The text contains the version number